# How to dynamically hide button based on whether table has rows or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to get anything to work. I am trying to hid the "Delete Selected Item" button when there are no table rows displayed after deleting all of the rows via the button. I have tried a few JQuery functions to no avail.

I currently have onclick events in place that call a javascript function to set the visibility of the button to hidden or visible but that doesn't seem to work either. I have been able to make the button visible via the add button but I can't seem to hide it again after the table is empty. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkFN(){ //function to check if there are rows in the table
    var x = document.getElementById("tasksFN").rows.length; //gives a variable to row length
   if(x == 0){ //checks if there is any data in table
        //if no data in table hides delete button
        document.getElementById("delFN").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
        //if data exists in table makes delete button visible
        document.getElementById("delFN").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkWM(){ //function to check if there are rows in the table
    var x = document.getElementById("tasksWM").rows.length; //gives a variable to row length
   if(x == 0){ //checks if there is any data in table
        //if no data in table hides delete button
        document.getElementById("delWM").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
        //if data exists in table makes delete button visible
        document.getElementById("delWM").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkBOH(){ //function to check if there are rows in the table
    var x = document.getElementById("tasksBOH").rows.length; //gives a variable to row length
   if(x == 0){ //checks if there is any data in table
        //if no data in table hides delete button
        document.getElementById("delBOH").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
        //if data exists in table makes delete button visible
        document.getElementById("delBOH").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkRAM(){ //function to check if there are rows in the table
    var x = document.getElementById("tasksRAM").rows.length; //gives a variable to row length
   if(x == 0){ //checks if there is any data in table
        //if no data in table hides delete button
        document.getElementById("delRAM").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }else{
        //if data exists in table makes delete button visible
        document.getElementById("delRAM").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<H2 align="center"><u>Enter New Tasks Below</u></H2> 
<H3 align="center">
Type your new task into the text box below and click "Add".<br><br>
Once a task or multiple tasks have been completed, check the box next to the task/tasks you would like to remove and click the "Delete Selected Items" button.</H3>

<div id="main" align"center">
<div class="unconFN">
    <table id="tasksFN" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4> <!-- textbox heading -->
        <input type="text" id="newFN" />  <!-- textbox for new data to be added -->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addFN" value="Add"  /> <!--button to add data from textbox to table -->
        <br /><br />
    </table/>
<br />
    <input type="button" id="delFN" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" onclick="checkFN()" />

    <script>
        //function to add text from textbox to table on button click
        $("#addFN").click(function() {
            //data to be added to table
            var val = $("#newFN").val();
            //prepends checkbox to data added to table
            var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');

    //creates new tr and td from the values entered in textbox
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
            //adds the data to the table
            $("#tasksFN").append(newTxt);
            //creates new empty row for next data set to be added
            $("#newFN").val("");
            //changes hidden attribute of delete button to make it visible
            $("#delFN").attr("hidden",false);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //function to delete checked rows from table on button click
            $("#delFN").click(function() {
                //checks to see whether checkbox is checked or not
                console.log($(".checkbox[checked='checked']"))
                //function to do an action on all rows with checked checkboxes
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    //sets variable for the rows with checked checkboxes
                    var curFN = $(this).parents('tr');
                    //deletes rows with checked checkboxes
                    curFN.remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div> <!-- end .unconFN div -->

<div class="unconWM">
    <table id="tasksWM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>WorkMarket UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4> <!-- textbox heading -->
        <input type="text" id="newWM" />  <!-- textbox for new data to be added -->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addWM" value="Add"  /> <!--button to add data from textbox to table -->
        <br /><br />
    </table/>
<br />
    <input type="button" id="delWM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" onclick="checkWM()"  />

    <script>
        //function to add text from textbox to table on button click
        $("#addWM").click(function() {
            //data to be added to table
            var val = $("#newWM").val();
            //prepends checkbox to data added to table
            var newWM = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');

    //creates new tr and td from the values entered in textbox
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
            //adds the data to the table
            $("#tasksWM").append(newWM);
            //creates new empty row for next data set to be added
            $("#newWM").val("");
            //changes hidden attribute of delete button to make it visible
            $("#delWM").attr("hidden",false);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //function to delete checked rows from table on button click
            $("#delWM").click(function() {
                //checks to see whether checkbox is checked or not
                console.log($(".checkbox[checked='checked']"))
                //function to do an action on all rows with checked checkboxes
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    //sets variable for the rows with checked checkboxes
                    var curWM = $(this).parents('tr');
                    //deletes rows with checked checkboxes
                    curWM.remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div> <!-- end .unconWM div -->

<div class="BOHswap">
    <table id="tasksBOH" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4> <!-- textbox heading -->
        <input type="text" id="newBOH" />  <!-- textbox for new data to be added -->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addBOH" value="Add"  /> <!--button to add data from textbox to table -->
        <br /><br />
    </table/>
<br />
    <input type="button" id="delBOH" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" onclick="checkBOH()"  />

    <script>
        //function to add text from textbox to table on button click
        $("#addBOH").click(function() {
            //data to be added to table
            var val = $("#newBOH").val();
            //prepends checkbox to data added to table
            var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');

    //creates new tr and td from the values entered in textbox
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
            //adds the data to the table
            $("#tasksBOH").append(newTxt);
            //creates new empty row for next data set to be added
            $("#newBOH").val("");
            //changes hidden attribute of delete button to make it visible
            $("#delBOH").attr("hidden",false);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //function to delete checked rows from table on button click
            $("#delBOH").click(function() {
                //checks to see whether checkbox is checked or not
                console.log($(".checkbox[checked='checked']"))
                //function to do an action on all rows with checked checkboxes
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    //sets variable for the rows with checked checkboxes
                    var curBOH = $(this).parents('tr');
                    //deletes rows with checked checkboxes
                    curBOH.remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div> <!-- end .BOHswap div -->

<div class="unRAM">
    <table id="tasksRAM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4> <!-- textbox heading -->
        <input type="text" id="newRAM" /> <!-- textbox for new data to be added -->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addRAM" value="Add"  /> <!--button to add data from textbox to table -->
        <br /><br />
    </table/>
<br />
    <input type="button" id="delRAM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" onclick="checkRAM()" />

    <script>

        //function to add text from textbox to table on button click
        $("#addRAM").click(function() {
            //data to be added to table
            var val = $("#newRAM").val(); 
            //prepends checkbox to data added to table
            var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');

        //creates new tr and td from the values entered in textbox
        $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
            //adds the data to the table
            $("#tasksRAM").append(newTxt);
            //creates new empty row for next data set to be added
            $("#newRAM").val("");
            //changes hidden attribute of delete button to make it visible
            $("#delRAM").attr("hidden",false);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //function to delete checked rows from table on button click
            $("#delRAM").click(function() {
                //checks to see whether checkbox is checked or not
                console.log($(".checkbox[checked='checked']"))
                //function to do an action on all rows with checked checkboxes
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    //sets variable for the rows with checked checkboxes
                    var curRAM = $(this).parents('tr');
                    //deletes rows with checked checkboxes
                    curRAM.remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div> <!-- end .unRAM div -->
</div> <!-- end #main div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById` not `Document.getElementById`

Comment: good catch, rookie mistake, still isn't working tho. :-( But I've update the code to reflect the change.

Comment: In the code you have provided, there are missing closing `}` for all the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all few suggestions. You have several syntax issues and moreover the code is not much readable. Always do not mix up script with html. That's really painful to read. Below is the updated `html` and `js` and a working **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hjdvhwmg/)**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//keep only one document.ready if possible and wrap all the js code in that
function checkFN(){
   var x = document.getElementById("tasksFN").rows.length;
   if(x == 0){
       $("#delFN").hide(); 
       //since you are anyways using jquery make use of it completely. Use .hide() and
       //.show() jquery methods to hide/show elements
   }else{
        $("#delFN").show();
   }
}

function checkWM(){
   var x = document.getElementById("tasksWM").rows.length;
   if(x == 0){
        $("#delWM").hide();
   }else{
        $("#delWM").show();
   }
}

function checkBOH(){
   var x = document.getElementById("tasksBOH").rows.length;
   if(x == 0){
        $("#delBOH").hide();
   }else{
        $("#delBOH").show();
   }
}

function checkRAM(){
    var x = document.getElementById("tasksRAM").rows.length;
    if(x == 0){
        document.getElementById("delRAM").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("delRAM").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

$("#delWM").click(function() {
    $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    checkWM();
});

$("#addWM").click(function() {
     var val = $("#newWM").val();
     var newWM = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $("#tasksWM").append(newWM);
     $("#newWM").val("");
     $("#delWM").show();
});
        
$("#addFN").click(function() {
     var val = $("#newFN").val();
     var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $("#tasksFN").append(newTxt);
     $("#newFN").val("");
     $("#delFN").show();
});

$("#delFN").click(function() {
     $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
     checkFN();//call the required function to check for data to work with delete button hide/show
});
    
$("#addBOH").click(function() {
     var val = $("#newBOH").val();
     var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $("#tasksBOH").append(newTxt);
     $("#newBOH").val("");
     $("#delBOH").show();
 });
    
 $("#delBOH").click(function() {
     $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
     checkBOH();
 });

 $("#addRAM").click(function() {
     var val = $("#newRAM").val();
     var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $("#tasksRAM").append(newTxt);
     $("#newRAM").val("");
     $("#delRAM").show();
 });
 
 $("#delRAM").click(function() {
  $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
     checkRAM();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 align="center"><u>Enter New Tasks Below</u></h2> 
<h3 align="center">
Type your new task into the text box below and click "Add".<br/><br/>
Once a task or multiple tasks have been completed, check the box next to the task/tasks you would like to remove and click the "Delete Selected Items" button.</h3>
<div class="unconFN">
    <table id="tasksFN" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
        <input type="text" id="newFN" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addFN" value="Add"  />
        <br /><br />
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="delFN" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
<div class="unconWM">
    <table id="tasksWM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>WorkMarket UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
        <input type="text" id="newWM" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addWM" value="Add"  />
        <br /><br />
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="delWM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true"  />
</div>

<div class="BOHswap">
    <table id="tasksBOH" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
        <input type="text" id="newBOH" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addBOH" value="Add"  />
        <br /><br />
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="delBOH" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>

<div class="unRAM">
    <table id="tasksRAM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
        <input type="text" id="newRAM" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addRAM" value="Add"  />
        <br /><br />
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="delRAM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true"  />
</div>
```

**Few Key Points to note**

- > Your `<table>` wasn't ending properly. It was like `</table/>`
  >   whereas it should have been `</table>`
- > Do not write inline `onclick` with elements like `<input type="button"
  >   id="delRAM" onclick="somefunc()"/>` since you are already handling
  >   `click event` for buttons. What happens is this function will be
  >   called first, it will checks for record existence and then it would go
  >   and delete each `checkbox`. So you need to call this `function` after
  >   `$.each` to check for records.
- > Always try to keep one `$(document).ready()` and wrap all your `js`
  >   code in that and this `$(document).ready()` is good if you keep just
  >   before `</body>` as `js` part should always come at end of `html` and 
  >   do not forget to keep this `$(document).ready()` inside `<script> type="text/javascipt"></script>`

Comment: I truly appreciate individuals like you whose help with in depth analysis and advice really make better coders of us all. You have made some great points and I will take your advice to heart for my future projects and many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. add http:// in the src of script tag
2. add closing braces to first 4 functions

After these changes the code seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, here is my attempt:

```js
var myTable = $('#myTable');
var prefixAddID = 'add';
var prefixDelID = 'del';
var prefixTasksID = 'tasks';
var prefixNewID = 'new';

$('#delFN, #delWM, #delBOH, #delRAM').on('click', deleteRow);
$('#addFN, #addWM, #addBOH, #addRAM').on('click', addRow);

function addRow() {
  var suffixID = $(this).attr('id').substr(prefixAddID.length);
  var value = $('#' + prefixNewID + suffixID).val();
  myTable.append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
  $('#' + prefixTasksID + suffixID).append($('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>'));
  $('#' + prefixNewID + suffixID).val('');
  $('#' + prefixDelID + suffixID).show();
}

function deleteRow() {
  var suffixID = $(this).attr('id').substr(prefixDelID.length);
  $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });
  var length = $('#' + prefixTasksID + suffixID)[0].rows.length;
  $('#' + prefixDelID + suffixID).toggle(length !== 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 align="center"><u>Enter New Tasks Below</u></h2>
<h3 align="center">
Type your new task into the text box below and click "Add".<br><br>
Once a task or multiple tasks have been completed, check the box next to the task/tasks you would like to remove and click the "Delete Selected Items" button.</h3>
<div class="unconFN">
  <table id="tasksFN" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
    <input type="text" id="newFN" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="addFN" value="Add" />
    <br />
    <br />
  </table>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="delFN" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
<div class="unconWM">
  <table id="tasksWM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <h4>WorkMarket UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
    <input type="text" id="newWM" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="addWM" value="Add" />
    <br />
    <br />
  </table>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="delWM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
<div class="BOHswap">
  <table id="tasksBOH" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
    <input type="text" id="newBOH" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="addBOH" value="Add" />
    <br />
    <br />
  </table>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="delBOH" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
<div class="unRAM">
  <table id="tasksRAM" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
    <input type="text" id="newRAM" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="addRAM" value="Add" />
    <br />
    <br />
  </table>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="delRAM" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
```

jsFiddle of which can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bs1xrmh7/)**. Hope this helps in some way though. I will add the details later.

***Details***

- The idea is that you should only have one `addRow` function and one `deleteRow` function to avoid repetitions.
- And this becomes possible thanks to the naming convention you are already using for your `id`s across your HTML elements. They all have a similar pattern.
- I wouldn't say that it is best to use so many `id`s in your markup as they can be replaced with `class` attributes but for now, I have only fixed a few issues in your markup (as stated by others) and, used pretty much the same markup.
- So in `addRow`, the uniqueness of the clicked `Add` button is taken by the `suffix` of its `id` e.g. `FN` and `WM` etc.
- The rest of the actions just use this unique suffix to do whatever needs to be done.
- For example, when `addFN` button is clicked, `tasksFN` needs to append a certain markup into it. So we take out `FN` from `addFN` and we combine that with `tasks` to make `tasksFN` selector.
- The rest is pretty self-explanatory.
- Similar stuff happens in `deleteRow` function.